# How to deploy a configured domain lab environment automatically?

Tags: powershell, vmware, automation, vsphere

I am looking for a quick way to spin up an entire domain environment (AD, Exchange, Web services, WSUS, DNS, Database, clients, etc.) in vSphere for a pen testing lab. I would like to test various security products so I am looking for a way to spin these up quickly and already configured. I've seen powershell scripts that do this for Hyper-V (Invoke-ADLabDeployer, AutomatedLab), but is there a way to make this work with VMware vSphere?

Comment: You've already asked [https://superuser.com/questions/1591280/how-can-i-spin-up-a-whole-domain-lab-environment-automatically] this question that it got closed. Why did you re-ask it?

Comment: @postanote It was closed and I was linked to "How TO ASK questions that may require a software solution:" which says to reword the question, which I did.

Comment: This question is the same as you closed one. [I am looking for a quick way to spin up an entire domain environment (AD, Exchange, Web services, WSUS, DNS, Database, clients, etc.) in vSphere for a pen testing lab.], this as far as I am aware does not exist. You’ll need to write this yourself, from scratch. Get the PowerShell ones, then download/install the VMW cmdlets, and use them to swap out the Hyper-V ones for the Hyper-V ones.  This is not hard, but it is tedious to do/takes weeks to pull together. Unless someone has already has this, you are asking folks to do this for you. Not a thing.

Comment: Expect folks to vote to close this one as well.

Comment: I am not asking anyone to do this for me, I am asking if this has been done before and if it's available somewhere because I cannot find it.

Comment: Again, understood, and that is what I said. Unless someone has already done this and has this to give to you, you are asking folks, if they have or will they search the web for you to find one, because you could not find it. So, same deal. Again, I've never seen this for VMW as I've been an all HV type, and very little VMW work, So, you are going to have to do it. Lastly, what you are asking for is far more that just a pristine lab. Pen-Testing labs means pre-hardened as well. Even teh HV ones don't do this. YOu have to harden after each time, or automate that as you need to.